# What is the purpose or meaning of a "relay" (UniRelay) here in the JDK8 source for CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm looking at the JDK8 source for [`uniComposeStage`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#L967), which is the implementation called for typical usages of `thenCompose`:

```
private <V> CompletableFuture<V> uniComposeStage(
    Executor e, Function<? super T, ? extends CompletionStage<V>> f) {
    if (f == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    Object r; Throwable x;
    if (e == null && (r = result) != null) {
        // try to return function result directly
        if (r instanceof AltResult) {
            if ((x = ((AltResult)r).ex) != null) {
                return new CompletableFuture<V>(encodeThrowable(x, r));
            }
            r = null;
        }
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") T t = (T) r;
            CompletableFuture<V> g = f.apply(t).toCompletableFuture();
            Object s = g.result;
            if (s != null)
                return new CompletableFuture<V>(encodeRelay(s));
            CompletableFuture<V> d = new CompletableFuture<V>();
            UniRelay<V> copy = new UniRelay<V>(d, g);
            g.push(copy);
            copy.tryFire(SYNC);
            return d;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            return new CompletableFuture<V>(encodeThrowable(ex));
        }
    }
    CompletableFuture<V> d = new CompletableFuture<V>();
    UniCompose<T,V> c = new UniCompose<T,V>(e, d, this, f);
    push(c);
    c.tryFire(SYNC);
    return d;
}
```

Most of the first half seems to be dealing with edge cases and initializers. The meat of the action is here:

```
            CompletableFuture<V> g = f.apply(t).toCompletableFuture();
            Object s = g.result;
            if (s != null)
                return new CompletableFuture<V>(encodeRelay(s));
            CompletableFuture<V> d = new CompletableFuture<V>();
            UniRelay<V> copy = new UniRelay<V>(d, g);
            g.push(copy);
            copy.tryFire(SYNC);
            return d;
```

Okay, so the `.toCompletableFuture()` is doing the famous "flattening" that `thenCompose` does over `thenApply`. But what does this `UniRelay` class have to do with anything? What's the meaning of a "relay" here?

Further up in the file you can also find the source for [`uniApplyStage`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#L610):

```
private <V> CompletableFuture<V> uniApplyStage(
    Executor e, Function<? super T,? extends V> f) {
    if (f == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    CompletableFuture<V> d =  new CompletableFuture<V>();
    if (e != null || !d.uniApply(this, f, null)) {
        UniApply<T,V> c = new UniApply<T,V>(e, d, this, f);
        push(c);
        c.tryFire(SYNC);
    }
    return d;
}
```

Much simpler. No use of a "relay." What does `thenCompose` do that `thenApply` doesn't that involves this other concept? I would have thought the "flattening" (and related exception-handling) would have been all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derp, answered my own question mid-writing it.

> We also include "Relay" classes/methods that don't correspond to user methods; they copy results from one stage to another.

And another hint here:

```
/**
 * Returns the encoding of a copied outcome; if exceptional,
 * rewraps as a CompletionException, else returns argument.
 */
static Object encodeRelay(Object r) {
    Throwable x;
    return (((r instanceof AltResult) &&
             (x = ((AltResult)r).ex) != null &&
             !(x instanceof CompletionException)) ?
            new AltResult(new CompletionException(x)) : r);
}
```

So to answer myself...

#### "Relay" in this context means copying the result of an inner stage to the outer stage's scope, in a way that's safe and consistent with how the CompletableFuture package was designed, and also handling exceptions.

In other words, it's a piece of the "flattening" magic—if you're gonna make it as if nested futures are all on one level and chainable, then you're also gonna have to make it as if their completed results are all on one level (hence, *relaying* them to the top level) and chainable.